# Managed Virtual Devices (XAP) is gray

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin installed and ADB.
I try to deploy C# Android "Hellow World" project to the emulator.
When I try run it on 5'' KitKat 4.4, it says that can not run device requiring 2056 Mb RAM even if I have more than 2G free.
If I try other choises, it says:

```
Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError --->
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error:     
Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

The follow problem is that "Managed Virtual Devices (XAP)" button is gray.

**UPDATE:**
If I run with Visual Studio Emulator, it gives me error about missing of VT support (despite VT support enabled in BIOS), see my post here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69468/publishing-xamarin-app-manually-with-adb

If I run with ADV, I have follow output:

```
1>    Processing: C:\Users\nurba\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.Platform\library_project_imports\res\values\strings.xml
1>  App1.Droid -> C:\Users\nurba\Documents\Visual Studio     2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\bin\Debug\App1.Droid.dll
1>    Processing: C:\Users\nurba\Documents\Visual Studio     2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.    Platform\library_project_imports\res\values\strings.xml
2>Starting deploy NewTest ...
2>Starting emulator NewTest ...
2>Emulator NewTest was stopped.
```

(Further localized)
Build: success
Deploy: one error

Comment: What emulator are you using? Take a look here if you need help with set up: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/

Do note that XAP (Xamarin Android Player) has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanx for reply, see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your forum post, it looks like you're trying to deploy a `Debug` signed application instead of a `Release` signed application that includes the runtime as well.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Application_Packages

`06-21 15:08:43.301 3186 3186 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!`

Overall you should ensure you are deploying a fully signed `Release` APK to any phones that have not already installed the `Shared Runtime`.

**Note:** You could set the `AndroidUseSharedRuntime` property to `false` in a Debug build if you wished, but I do not recommend it.

**i.e:** `<AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>`